# Jquery sockets not connecting

Tags: jquery, sockets

I'm using the JQuery sockets from [here](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-websocket/). I'm trying to connect my browser to an erlang server through a socket and having tested the erlang server I can safely assume it accepts connections however just to be safe here it is:

```
-module(browser).
-export([start/0]).


start() ->
    BossProc = spawn(fun() -> listenerSocket([]) end),
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(2266,[binary,{packet,4}]),
    sloop(Listen, BossProc).

sloop(Listen,BossProc)->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    io:format("Someone connected"),
    BossProc ! {Socket},
    spawn(fun() -> sloop(Listen, BossProc) end),
    receive
        {tcp, Socket, Bin} -> BossProc ! {broadcast, Bin};
        {tcp_closed, Socket} -> io:format("Someone disconnected")
    end.



listenerSocket(A) -> 
    receive 
        {Socket} -> listenerSocket(lists:append(A,[Socket]));
        {broadcast, Msg} -> [J ! {Msg} || J <- A]
    end.
```

Here is my script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ws = $.websocket("127.0.0.1:2266/", {
        events: {
                message: function(e) { console.log(e.data) }
        }
});

});
```

The problem is that although this code executes I receive no confirmation from my erlang server ("Someone connected" is not displayed). Here is the HTML where the script runs:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.websocket-0.0.1.js"></script>
        <scrcpt src="js/brain.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea col = "20" rows = "20" id="text" disabled="true"></textarea><br>
        <input type = "text" id = "input" size="25"/><br>
        <input type = "button" id="entry" value="Enter" />
    </body>


</html>
```

I'm sure it's a very basic error however I can't see exactly where the code stops or if it even runs

Comment: WebSocket will only run in later versions of some browsers. Make sure your browser is Internet Explorer 10 or above, Firefox 31 or above or Chrome 31 or above. If it's anything else check that WebSocket is supported.

Comment: @Drummad I checked it on the latest version of chrome and firefox and I still don't see any confirmation

Comment: You may need to try prefixing your url with "ws://". Not too sure about that but it's worth a try!